# how do i install gthread-2.0 for mac?

Tags: c, dependencies, gnu, glibc, fuse

I am trying to compile sshfs: https://github.com/osxfuse/sshfs

Running the ./configure script outputs:

```
./configure: line 3676: syntax error near unexpected token `SSHFS,'
./configure: line 3676: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(SSHFS, fuse >= 2.3 glib-2.0 gthread-2.0)'
```

So I go here: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/download.html in order to install libC.

However, I get this message:

```
*** The GNU C library is currently not available for this platform.
*** So far nobody cared to port it and if there is no volunteer it
*** might never happen.  So, if you have interest to see glibc on
*** this platform visit
*** http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/porting.html
*** and join the group of porters
```

This is after I found out I needed to install other dependencies like gettext, libffi, glib2.

I'm running on a OS X 10.7.1 Lion.

Does this mean I cannot compile SSHFS or am I doing something wrong? It doesn't make sense they would give me the source code for SSHFS on the "Fuse for OSX" website but it doesn't compile on macs.

EDIT:

After installing glib I did the following:

```
pkg-config --libs --cflags --modversion gthread-2.0
2.38.1
-D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/lib/glib-2.0/include  -L/usr/local/lib -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

This proves I have gthread-2.0.

I also did:

```
pkg-config --libs --cflags --modversion glib-2.0
2.38.1
-I/usr/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/lib/glib-2.0/include  -L/usr/local/lib -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

This proves I have glib-2.0.

but I still get the error message on line 3676 above saying PKG_CHECK_MODULES unexpected token "sshfs".   Does this mean something is wrong with the PKG_CHECK_MODULES macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not confuse [GNU C Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (glibC) and [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/) (GLib is a general-purpose utility library).

What do you really need is to install Glib (not GlibC) on your MacOS. Please follow the manual which you will find on their web site, it will provide you with the steps how to install it on your MacOS.

Comment: I downloaded the source code from here: http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/glib/2.38/glib-2.38.1.tar.xz and did: ./configure; make; make install.  Then I attempted to run the ./configure script for SSHFS again and I get that same error message - namely `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(SSHFS, fuse >= 2.3 glib-2.0 gthread-2.0)'

Comment: I think the problem is I have not installed "gthread-2.0".  but I don't know where to get it?

Comment: gthread comes with Glib installation (it's part of GLib). Have you installed Fuse development files ?

Comment: I just installed the FUSE DMG.  Does this include development files?

Comment: Specifically: http://sourceforge.net/projects/osxfuse/files/osxfuse-2.6.1/osxfuse-2.6.1.dmg/download

Comment: what does ```pkg-config --libs --cflags --modversion fuse``` print for you ?

Comment: the output is: 2.7.3
-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE -I/usr/local/include/osxfuse/fuse  -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -losxfuse -liconv

Comment: is it possible the PKG_CHECK_MODULES macro is not correctly configured ? So even though I have all the dependencies it still reports that I don't?

Comment: try to reinstall pkg-config / autoconf / automake / libtool (using ```brew```). It looks like something is really broken on your system.

Comment: I opened the "configure" script and navigated to line 3676 and commented it out.  After doing that I was able to successfully execute the configure script.  However when I do "make" it complains about not knowing where "fuse.h" is.  I tracked it down to /usr/local/include/osxfuse/fuse.h.  If I replace #include <fush.h> with the absolute path then it is happy.  any way- I am marking your answer as correct because you technically answered my question.  If I need more help I'll post another question.

Comment: you don't really ever need to modify ```configure``` file, as it's an automatically generated script (configure.ac usually is the source of it).